# AWS directory service not able to login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I've created AWS Directory directory service and then create EC2 windows 2008 r2 instance and then I've changed the domain windows 2008 r2 domain to my AWS directory service domain then receive a message saying "Welcome to the Domain." Click OK and reboot your machine to finish joining the Domain. After reboot, log into that machine using the  AWS Directory  service  DomianName\Administrator and password. I am getting an error which shows in attached screen. [image]

let me know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message provided is accurate: you need to add the domain user to the local security group called Remote Desktop Users.

You AD login is fine. The local machine is rejecting it.